# How do i enable webgl 2.0 in Google chrome browser?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, webgl, webgl2

I am trying to enable WebGL 2.0 in my google Chrome browser but unsuccessful.
If any of you have faced such issue and have a solution, please share it. It would be a great help!

Before posting it here, I had spent decent time on web to fix the issue. But nothing had worked out.

### (I) Here is what I've ALREADY tried.

1. Use hardware acceleration in chrome://settings
2. Enabled WEBGL 2.0 in chrome://flags
3. Enabled WebGL Draft Extensions in chrome://flags
4. Override software render list in chrome://flags
5. Finally tried uninstalled and reinstalled chrome browser

---

### (II) About Chrome version and Other details:

1. My Chrome browser version is 61.0.3163.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)
2. I am running Chrome browser in a Windows 10 64 bit DELL laptop.
3. Webgl 2.0 works without any issues in Mozilla firefox browser in the same machine.
4. I checked www.webglreport.com to check WebGL 2.0 support for my browser. The following message is displayed there.

   "This browser supports WebGL 2, but it is disabled or unavailable.
   Sometimes this is the result of older video drivers being rejected by the browser. Try updating your video drivers if possible."
5. Webgl 1.0 works fine without any issues in the same machine.
6. My GL_RENDERER is "ANGLE (Intel(R) HD Graphics 530 Direct3D9Ex vs_3_0 ps_3_0)" & GL_VERSION is OpenGL ES 2.0. for chrome
   as seen from  chrome://gpu
7. I've AMD graphics card in my machine (Amd Firepro W5130M) 
   I am unable to make my Chrome browser use this graphics card. It always uses the inbuilt Intel card described in the above step.
8. I made sure that, both my graphic cards are not black listed and they are upto date.

What other option are out there to enable webgl 2.0 from chrome browser settings? 
I am desperate. Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I believe I understood (need verification) Firefox is in fact using either DirectX or even a pure software rendering for WebGL, while chrome directly links it to OpenGL. And this is why Firefox WebGL performances are sometime (if not always) terrible compared to Chrome. But another possible side effect, is that while Chrome directly ask the drivers if "OpenGL ES 3.0" is supported (and so, could get a "NO WAY" from the driver), Firefox don't and simply fallback in software/hybrid rendering. So it is possible that your driver actually doesn't supports GL ES 3.0, despite the fact Firefox works.

Comment: @Sedenion [I don't think so](https://chromium.googlesource.com/angle/angle/+/master/README.md)

Comment: Well, ANGLE is one thing, how Firefox deals with CG drivers is another one. I personally experienced thing described here in the question. I discovered that Firefox were actually using some software-rendering while Chrome was simply "disciplined" (my drivers was not properly installed)... However, that was under Linux. But since Firefox uses an DirectX based engine to render simple web pages, who knows what it did with WebGL. (I personally suspect Firefox to do some ugly things... anyway, this is the case under Linux: 80Fps Firefox versus 1500Fps Chromium, hem... how to say ?)

Comment: @Sedenion, Chrome does not use OpenGL on Windows and Firefox does not use software rendering for WebGL2 ever

Comment: Try running Chrome with `--use-angle=gl`.